# ASP.NET Index of parent repeater item (in nested repeaters)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a nested repeaters, i.e. a parent repeater and a child repeater. The child repeater contains only one DropDownList control. I have OnSelectedIndexChanged setup on DropDownList control. I can get the index of the child repeater item when the drop down list's selection is changed.

My question is: How can I get the index of the parent repeater in which the drop down list's selection was changed.

Here is the sample code:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="ParentRepeater">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="ChildRepeater">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownInChildRepeater" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownInChildRepeater_OnSelectedIndexChanged" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>


protected void DropDownInChildRepeater_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dropDownInChildRepeater = (DropDownList)sender;
    var dropDownInChildRepeaterItem = (RepeaterItem)dropDownInChildRepeater.NamingContainer;

    var indexOfDropDownInChildRepaterItem = dropDownInChildRepeater.ItemIndex;

    //Question I need index of ParentRepeater in which sender resides
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track with the `NaminContainer`. You just need to go up the control tree. DropDownList > RepeaterItem > Repeater > RepeaterItem.

```
//dropdown in child repeater
var dropDownInChildRepeater = (DropDownList)sender;

//repeater item in child repeater
var dropDownInChildRepeaterItem = (RepeaterItem)dropDownInChildRepeater.NamingContainer;

//child repeater
var childRepeater = (Repeater)dropDownInChildRepeaterItem.NamingContainer;

//repeateritem of parent repeater
var parentRepeaterItem = (RepeaterItem)childRepeater.NamingContainer;

//the item index of the parent repeateritem
var parentRepeaterItemIndex = parentRepeaterItem.ItemIndex;
```